# alert when containment limit is reached

Tags: jquery, draggable

Can somebody tell me how to display an alert when containment limits are reached?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "containment limits"?

Comment: If you mean when the dragged object reaches the droppable item and you need visual feedback, you need to set the hoverClass parameter and use CSS to style the droppable with that class.

Comment: I assume he means when the user drags to the bounds of the element set as the containment

Comment: If you mean what most people think here, I would not do this. If you show an alert, the focus is moved to the popup and the element is not dragged anymore (meaning the connection element <-> mouse is lost after the popup is closed). This can annoy the user.

Comment: Lets say my containment value is: [400, 0, 50, 0] for an x-axis draggable, I want to be able to have an alert when 400 or 50 are reached. That's all, thanks for your interest.

Comment: Just want the alert as an example on how to launch a function, thanks Felix

Comment: containment breach triggers a red alert on my equipment. what sort of starship are YOU driving?

Comment: +1 , cause i don't like when one downvote for nothing! but hey Moustard you got the answer to your problem! if you need further assistance pay someone for that! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that the position isn't changing when the [drag event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-drag) is occuring, like this:

```
var position = {};
$("#draggable").draggable({ 
  containment: 'document',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    if(position.top == ui.position.top && position.left == ui.position.left) {
      alert("Constrained");
      return false;
    }
    position = ui.position;
 }
});​
```

[You can play with a demo of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/WZWV9/1/)

Comment: The example works but...
How to prevent the multiple alerts?
If I trigger a function instead an alert, will the function be executed as many times as alert does?

Comment: @Moustard - It alerts when you're preventing from dragging because you hit a constraint, it only alerts when you dragged and hit it again.  As Felix notes in comments, I'm not sure this is the behavior you *want* once you think about it.  If you do a function in here, it'll be executed every time they hit the edge...if that's not what you want, then think about it, how would you say I want to run it this time, but not that time?  Unless it's time based, there's not a great way to throttle here.

Comment: So... How to launch a function only once when the limits are reached?
I can set a global and only run the function while it is false...
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Moustard - The above does this already...however every time you drag and are constained, *the limits are reached*, so that's not *actually* what you're after...you want something in-between, but unless you can define what that limit is...you can't code it :)

Comment: hmmm, sorry, I'm lost.
What do you mean with "What that limit is..."

Comment: @Moustard - When you drag and hit a wall, the answer I posted alerts, it alerts *only* then.  If you drag again, hit another wall, it alerts again, it does it once per constraint hit...if you want it to do it less often than that, then "when you hit a constraint" isn't an accurate description of what you're after...you need to define whatever it is you're *actually* going for...until you do that you can't really write code to do it, since you're after an unknown.

Comment: definitely +1 for this code! why the OP have not checked it yet!?

Comment: Nick, you are right and the answer really solves my question.
First of all, I'm a designer, not a programmer, I apologyze for me shaky knowledges.
The problem I have with this UI is that when the containment limits are reached the drag event keeps triggering, but the fact is that you are not dragging anymore...
Or maybe this is not accurately expressed.
If we consider it in terms of physics, your function detects a collision, but when a car hits a wall, collision is finish, no matter if the wheels keep turning against the wall.

Comment: @Moustard - The `return false` prevents that and cancels further dragging...did you try the demo?

Comment: When I try the demo I get a lot of alerts, at least in FF 3.6.3, so the dragging seems to continue... :(

Comment: @Moustard - You're right firefox is screwing with it, you can add an additional check for that, demo updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/WZWV9/3/

Comment: With this new demo I get a big delay between the collision and the alert, do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: @Moustard - Alerts are *not* like normal code, use `console.log()` to see it real-time, alerts are just testing, not really that accurate for event timing.

Comment: Can you please explain what `var position = {};` does?